# O. Gabber, Non-negativity of Serre’s intersection multiplicities

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, article-writing

This article is cited here and there, but I cannot find it anywhere.

> Gabber, O. (1995), Non-negativity of Serre’s intersection multiplicities, Expos ́e `a L’IHES

I checked author's publications, and there are none in 1995.

Answer (score 6):

I have seen this referred to as a preprint before - perhaps this implies it is not formally published and only informally available. I suggest emailing the authors of the papers you've seen citations of this article in - it may produce a copy. In the meantime, the best available published article I can find is an accounting of "Recent Developments on Serre's Multiplicity Conjectures: Gabber's Proof of the Nonnegativity Conjecture" by Paul C. Roberts, published in L'Enseignement Mathématique in 1998.

[Here](https://www.worldcat.org/title/recent-developments-on-serres-multiplicity-conjectures-gabbers-proof-of-the-nonnegativity-conjecture/oclc/937364235&referer=brief_results) is the Worldcat listing, which contains a link to a freely-available online copy of the article [here](https://www.e-periodica.ch/digbib/view?pid=ens-001:1998:44::182#598). It may be browsed both on the website or via downloading a PDF.

---

**Edit**: Takumi Murayama has helpfully added the following two sources referred to in this paper in the comments below: [Berthelot's Séminaire Bourbaki talk](http://www.numdam.org/item/SB_1995-1996__38__273_0/) and [Hochster's exposition of Gabber's result](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~hochster/mult.pdf).

Comment: One can also look at Berthelot's [Séminaire Bourbaki talk](http://www.numdam.org/item/SB_1995-1996__38__273_0) and at Hochster's [exposition of Gabber's result](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~hochster/mult.pdf).

Comment: @TakumiMurayama ah, excellent! I saw this referenced but I did not think to check Hochster's website for a copy.